# Which package currently provides nmblookup command on Gentoo?

Tags: samba, cifs, gentoo

I currently installed samba on my gentoo server with following

```
USE="acl client fam python upcall winbind" emerge -1 samba
```

But could not find the nmblookup utility after install.
The samba package installed was version 3.6.18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nmblookup` is provided by `USE=client net-fs/samba`

```
 $ type nmblookup && equery belongs $(type nmblookup | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
nmblookup is /usr/bin/nmblookup
 * Searching for /usr/bin/nmblookup ...
net-fs/samba-3.6.16 (/usr/bin/nmblookup)
$ grep -B2 nmblookup /usr/portage/net-fs/samba/samba-3.6.16.ebuild
        if use client ; then
                BINPROGS="${BINPROGS} bin/smbclient bin/net bin/smbget bin/smbtree
                        bin/nmblookup bin/smbpasswd bin/rpcclient bin/smbcacls bin/smbcquotas
```

---

`net-fs/samba-3.6.18` is not in the main portage tree.

```
$ sudo emerge --sync --quiet && equery keywords samba
Keywords for net-fs/samba:
                |                           | u   |
                | a a             p     s   | n   |
                | l m   h i m m   p s   p   | u s | r
                | p d a p a 6 i p c 3   a x | s l | e
                | h 6 r p 6 8 p p 6 9 s r 8 | e o | p
                | a 4 m a 4 k s c 4 0 h c 6 | d t | o
----------------+---------------------------+-----+-------
      3.5.21    | + + + + + o ~ + + + + + + | o 0 | gentoo
      3.5.22    | ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ o ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ | o   | gentoo
   [I]3.6.16    | + + + + + o o + + o o + + | o   | gentoo
      3.6.19    | ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ o o ~ ~ o o ~ ~ | o   | gentoo
    [M]4.0.8-r2 | o ~ o ~ o o o o o o o o ~ | o   | gentoo
    [M]4.0.9    | o ~ o ~ o o o o o o o o ~ | o   | gentoo
[M]4.1.0_rc3    | o ~ o ~ o o o o o o o o ~ | o   | gentoo
[M]4.1.0_rc4    | o ~ o ~ o o o o o o o o ~ | o   | gentoo
```

Perhaps you should stop using whatever overlay provider(s) you've got configured for this package and use the main one.

```
$ emerge --pretend --getbinpkg --quiet samba::gentoo
[binary   R   ] net-fs/samba-3.6.16
```

Comment: He should also check his useflags.  I'm using 3.6.19 from the main tree and it has it.

Comment: Hum I using the profile: default/linux/amd64/13.0 with ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="~amd64". Perhaps should not put it on make.conf and write individual package masking. I will try downgrade to 3.6.16.